# How to use a display mode that's not in the list of available modes?

Tags: pygame, raspberry-pi-zero

My display's native resolution is 320x480 but pygame's `pygame.display.list_modes()` doesn't include it. When I try to set it, I get 640x480 instead, which is in the list. How can I use the native resolution?

320x480 is also the resolution the framebuffer is in when my program starts and pygame correctly detects that, so a way to get pygame to just continue using the existing mode would solve the problem too.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
    
print(pygame.display.list_modes())
  # Prints [(1600, 1200), (1280, 1024), (1024, 1024), (1280, 960), (1152, 864), (1024, 768), (800, 600), (768, 576), (640, 480)]

width = pygame.display.Info().current_w
height = pygame.display.Info().current_h
print(width, height)
  # Correctly prints 320 480

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
surface.fill((255, 0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
  # Uses 640x480 letterboxed twice to become really small.
```

[image: 320x480 too small]

The 320x480 mode is set in /boot/config.txt as a custom mode using

```
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 480 320 60 6 0 0 0
display_hdmi_rotate 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the mode to /etc/fb.modes like this:

```
mode "320x480-60"
    geometry 320 480 320 480 8
endmode
```

Comment: Yes. Its solves the problem by adding that mode to the list of available modes.